# Reusing existing build task of TFS2015 in a new custom build task

Tags: build, tfs-2015, vnext

We are using TFS2015 release management in our project. To perform a specific build i need to add multiple task (around 50). I can group these build task in 5 logical groups. As these logical groups will be reusable, I am thinking to create a new custom build task and add the already available build task in my new custom build task.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: The task group is reusable that can be added to a build or release definition (I updated my answer). What's the detail requirement of adding available build task to custom build task?

Answer (score 0):

The [Task group](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/library/task-groups) is reusable task that can be added to a build or release definition, just like any other task. So you just need to group necessary tasks into a group and add this group to build or release.

Steps to group tasks and use in the build or release:

1. Open a build/release definition
2. Select some tasks and right click > Create task group
3. Open a build/release definition
4. Add step/task> select corresponding task group > Add

You can’t add already available build/release task in the custom build task, but you can refer to the source code of these tasks and copy necessary code to your custom build task script (many script files can be loaded/referenced to your script file directly).

Regarding source code of build tasks, you can get it in `[agent folder]\tasks` folder (all the tasks that used in the build will be downloaded to tasks folder) or refer to this site: [vsts-tasks](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks).